# Performance of the python Z3 API

Tags: python, performance, z3

Is there any difference in performance between using the python API of Z3 instead of directly interacting with the C implementation through SMT-Lib files for instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is measurable overhead of using the python API to build and traverse terms compared to the C/C++ APIs.

Comment: First of all thanks for the prompt answer!
I usually make a difference between the time required for building the formulas and the solving time (the time spent solving an already added formula). From you answer it's not yet clear to me if the overhead is rather in the building or the solving phase. Concretely speaking, once a formula is built and added to the solver, are there still differences in the performance?